configure nginx to close connection when upstream has sent its response
I would like to configure Nginx such that it stops reading from a (potentially large) client POST request and just close the connection once the upstream server has sent a response.
In my setup I am in certain conditions able to quickly determine whether a client response is invalid, e.g. because headers are missing. In my Python/Django server (running on Gunicorn) I do a streaming read from the request, and once I've established some error condition I just send the response accordingly and close the connection.
I have established that this indeed works as described, for the setup with Gunicorn, by doing a large (and artificially slowed down) invalid POST request from a test script; that script "gets the message" that no further sending is possible once the response has been received.
However, in the production setup Gunicorn is behind Nginx. The relevant conf is:
    location / {
        # Pass the request to Gunicorn via proxy_pass.
        proxy_pass                  http://127.0.0.1:8000;

In this setup the client will keep sending to the Nginx server, even when Gunicorn has already closed the connection.
How do I instruct nginx to pass on the connection-close to the client?
